# CAN Bus Frame Error

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, can, sharedbus

3.3 CAN Controller. Recessive state 1.85V...Talking to third party 5V CAN. Recessive state 2.4V. Both have dominant differentials of >= 2V. Two 120 ohm resistors on bus, 63 ohm resistance throughout.

250kbps. Timing settings seem OK. With 5V device disconnected, 3.3V CAN gets ACK error (expected — only device on bus). Then attaching 5V device, 3.3V reports frame error after every interrupt. 5V device is dominating network then and keeps transmitting.

3.3V CAN says interoperable with 5V CANs. Bit of a CAN newbie...something ring a bell here? Perhaps recessive states too different? Tx and Rx to 3.3V MCU behaving.

EDIT: When I say CAN, I mean transceiver. I have an MCU controlling my 3.3V CAN transceiver (TCAN332), and the MCU has driver and example code to control comm with transceiver. There’s 12V on the bus. The frame error is from my 3.3V CAN receiving from the third party 5V CAN device. Thank you all.

Comment: What are you using for drivers, if anything?

Comment: Did you forget to connect CAN_GND?

Comment: Does the 3.3V device receive data from 5V device? You say it 'keeps transmitting', but it's not very clear what you mean.

Comment: Drivers came with MCU that's talking to my 3.3V transceiver. Compatible. Ground is connected. Yes, the 3.3V transceiver receives data from the 5V. But, there is a frame error every time. The lines look pretty clean...there is a slight decline/incline on the dominant ends sometimes when the 5V is transmitting.

Comment: Schematics, please.

Answer (score 1):

The idle voltage levels on CANH and CANL are standardized at 2.5V. If you have anything else, it is broken and shouldn't be used. There is nothing called "3.3V CAN" or "5V CAN".

This assuming that you even have CAN, meaning that each node has a *CAN controller* and a *CAN transceiver*. The controller is built-in inside a MCU on all modern systems, whereas the CAN transceiver is most often an external circuit.

3.3V versus 5V refers to the levels on the controller side of the transceiver, on the TXD and RXD signals, which need to be be the same as used by the controller/MCU. Those levels are irrelevant to the voltage levels on the bus itself.

Regarding 3.3V transceivers generating slightly different voltage levels, see this [app note from TI](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=SLLA337&fileType=pdf&keyMatch=slla337&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything).

Comment: There are CAN tranceivers that operate on 3.3V, eg: SN65HVD232

Comment: @Jeroen3 Yes, that's what I said - you can have different voltage levels on the controller side. But that doesn't affect the levels on the CAN bus side.

Comment: Yes it does. The 3.3V tranceiver has different single ended voltages, and uses 0.2V common mode shift to function.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Well it affects them but not outside the spec. The differential voltage levels are what matter. See the app note I linked.

Comment: @Lundin This is my understanding as well. As long as the transceivers have sufficient differential voltages when dominant, 5V + 3.3V transceivers should co-exist. We have no prior experience, though.

Comment: @ALamp I do this all the time, with all manner of transceivers. Both the mentioned 3V3 from TI as well as TI's 5V equivalents, NXP, Microchip, LT, Maxim etc etc.

Comment: @Lundin We get frame errors followed by stuff errors...so were wondering if perhaps it was due to the decent recessive difference. Still looking for answer. Thank you all for the comments

Comment: @ALamp Could be lots of causes for error frames. Maybe post a new question with schematics and connections, possibly CAN logs or scope logs, driver code and whatever else that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

3.3V CAN and 5V CAN are only ever loosely described by the manufacturer as "Possibly compatible", In my own experiences it rarely ever works reliably in the field.

The issue is the CAN High threshold

A number of receivers have quite a heavy hysteresis on there inputs to have a high immunity to noise, from previous testing, about 1/3 VCC to register a low, and above 2/3 VCC to register a high,

For your 3.3V CAN, this means its very marginal, as 3.3V is not certain to always trigger the 5V Can high threshold.

If you do want them to play nice, you may need to find out the part number of your 5V tranciver, and swap it with a pin compatible one if its logic thresholds are incompatible

Comment: This is simply not true. I combine SN65HVD232 (3V3) with various 5V transceivers (like MPC2551) all the time. This works just fine out of the box and I've never had problems with it, so I'm not sure where your "experience that it rarely ever works" is from. The 3V3 roughly keeps to the standardized voltage levels, which is fine since it's a differential signal anyway. See this app note: http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=SLLA337&fileType=pdf&keyMatch=slla337&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything

Comment: You are mistaking the logic side and the bus side. The question is about the bus side.

Comment: @Lundin My understanding is that of Lundin's in that the two should be able to co-exist...as in the TI app note. We have 12V on the bus/backbone.